# I want a subtotal when count of values for one column or two column is greater than one in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a situation where I have a table like this.
[image]

I want the totals under the creative column only when the count of CDJ is greater than 1. else it would be like as per the screenshot. Basically if we have categories, sub categories and sub sub categories and having sub totals and grand totals for each hierarchy, the subtotals or sub sub totals where these are only one will be redundant.  So i have to remove these redundant sub sub totals.

I tried many ways, but can't able to figure out a way to do it.

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean it should appear in view but subtotals of such cases should not appear in view?  I think there is no such way

Comment: yeah, essentially, the subtotal under CDJ is fine,  I only want subtotal under the creative name when the count of CDJ values is greater than 1.

Comment: I understood.  In case of sub category the subtotals would be a repeat.  But I think that may not be possible.

Comment: hmm, sounds interesting. but please check if you find anything. I am also looking into it.

Comment: Try proceeding like this http://vizdiff.blogspot.com/2019/11/hiding-subtotals-at-single-subcategory.html?m=1 i think you could do this workaround